# Read File from another server using FTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

He Everyone,

I am trying to get files from FTP 1 to FTP 2 using FTP functions in PHP. I am able to locate the files and get the list too from FTP 2. But I do not know how can I copy those files to FTP 1. This is how far I have reached.

```
$ftp_server    = "********";
$ftp_user_name = "******";
$ftp_user_pass = "******";
$ftp_dir       = "*********";
$mode          = "list_xml_files";

$file_list = ftp_list_xml_files ($ftp_server,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass,$ftp_dir,$mode,$file);

print_r($file_list);
die;
```

Upto this point it is working perfectly and here is the output of $file_list

```
Array ( [0] => orders01-04-2014.xml [1] => orders02-04-2014.xml )
```

Now I want to place these two xmls on FTP 1... Any idea how can I copy both of them an d put them on my FTP 1?

Thanks

Comment: PHP has a whole extension dedicated to FTP [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: as i mentioned i am really unable to make the logic out...after connecting, i have the list of files but how do i connect to two ftps in order to pass file between them?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/function.file-put-contents) and [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to do it.

```
<?php
    file_put_contents($save_location, fopen($filename, 'r'));
?>
```

And you could use that to download all the files you specified in the array using foreach:

```
<?php
    foreach($file_list as $filename)
        file_put_contents($save_location, fopen($filename, 'r'));
?>
```

And you would replace $save_location with a location on your server where you wish to download the file. Example:

```
$location = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/files/downloads";
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I placed your code in there but i get the same warnings and errors which i received earlier

Comment: Warning: fopen(orders01-04-2014.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in.........

Comment: You have to supply the _full_ url in order for this to work. Example: fopen("http://www.example.com/files/orders01-04-2014.xml");